# Override of commerce-order-receipt.html.twig template not working?

Tags: theming, commerce

My theme is using Bootstrap barrio theme (bootstrap_barrio) as a base theme. I'm trying to override Drupal commerce template `modules/contrib/commerce/modules/order/templates/commerce-order-receipt.html.twig` and it's not working for me. Even I copied that file to drupal/web/themes/my_theme/templates ,cleared the cache, Commerce is still using original template file from commerce module.

What puzzles me is that base Barrio theme also has that template and it's also not used?!?

Do I have to set somewhere what theme should be used for email templates or something? Overriding other modules templates (including commerce templates) works fine. Documentation says "The email can be customized by overriding the Twig template in your theme just as you would any other template".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Figured out what was the problem. I had to select my theme for sending emails on

**Configure the Mail System** admin page.

/admin/config/system/mailsystem

Other way some other theme is used.

Comment: Thanks @MilanG. That's already the second problem you asked about and helped me out :)